# Can you calculate the Area under the ROC curve (or C-statistic) using logistic regression from case control data?

Tags: logistic, case-control-study

I know you can estimate odds ratios based on logistic regression of case control data because the baseline risks cancel out. Does this mean that only the intercept is contaminated by the analysis of case control data in logistic regression?

And furthermore, does this mean that the predictions are all off by the same fixed constant (additive on the logistic scale; multiplicative on the probability scale) so that you can still maintain the proper ordering?

If the answer is "yes", doesn't that mean you can still calculate the AUC (C-statistic) because all it relies on is the proper ordering of the predicted values?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. Only the intercept is skewed by case-control data, but all AUC cares about is the ordering of the prediction scores. Even if the scores are $0.1$ for negatives and $0.2$ for positives, that's still a ROC AUC of $1$ because all positives are ranked more highly than all negatives.

In case you need a citation, Agresti's *Categorical Data Analysis* discusses the properties of case-control logistic regression, the salient details of which you've outlined.

Comment: thank you! Does this also mean I can do things like the Hosmer-Lemeshow lack of fit test, knowing that both the predictions and the outcomes are off by the same fixed multiplicative constant?

Comment: @casecontrol_logistic I don't know about that test but you could ask a new question about it. If you've found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Actually, I found it on my own! https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20527013 thanks again SY